# Android activity memory management

Tags: java, android, memory-management

I just started writing my first android application and have a question on its memory management.

In my app I have only one Main Activity, with two member variable -

```
private ArrayList<String> textList
private int textSize;
```

Application keep adding items into the textList and textSize keep track of items (I know about textList.size())

Going back to home screen without closing the application (pressing home button) to keep  phone idle for a prolonged time have result in

```
textList.size() = 0 and textSize = previous stored value.
```

I'm trying to understand the rational behind loosing values in textList and textSize keeping its value.

Comment: It could be that the initialization code called again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the application is not in the foreground Android may close it ... calling onDestroy().
I guess though since some state is being saved, then the Activity is itself not being reallocated, but instead you are probably reinitializing the textList in a Activity lifecycle function, like onResume().

See "Activity Lifecycle" on the Activity page (from developer.android.com)

Android could also release and reallocate your activity at times - so you cannot rely on member variables to preserve your state when you are not in the foreground.
If you want to save state, see "Saving Persistent State" and "onSaveInstanceState()" in the Activity android docs.